# Printing double-size characters with Ncurses

Tags: terminal, ncurses, terminfo

Many terminal emulators (xterm, Konsole) support [double-size characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:VTTEST-doublesize.png). Ncurses does not support this and as far as I know, ncurses will not print escape characters (\033 will be unescaped and printed in clear text).

Is it possible at all to print double-size characters in a ncurses application?

Answer (score 7):

The "double-size" character capability you refer to is set by the following ANSI sequences (found [here](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Controls-beginning-with-ESC:ESC-pound-3.EB4)):

```
ESC # 3   DEC double-height line, top half (DECDHL), VT100.
ESC # 4   DEC double-height line, bottom half (DECDHL), VT100.
ESC # 5   DEC single-width line (DECSWL), VT100.
ESC # 6   DEC double-width line (DECDWL), VT100.
```

The `\e#3` attribute makes the terminal switch character sets to one which only contains the top-half of each character. Similarly, `\e#4` switches to a character set containing the bottom-half. By using these together,

```
echo -e "\e#3Foo\n\e#4Foo"
```

the terminal can display a "double-height" text on two separate lines.

As far as I can tell you're right - ncurses hasn't "implemented" them - perhaps because they rely on a specialized fontset originally unique to DECTerminals.

Getting to the point, **it doesn't seem possible** since ncurses has no *attribute* for this feature, although I admittedly can't find any reference directly stating that it isn't possible. Perhaps someone with crazy terminfo skills can explain why this is (or isn't) the case.

Comment: Technically they are not ANSI sequences, they are DEC vendor sequences.  ECMA-48 shows the ANSI sequences: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm