# How can i get light green ansi code and get bigger font for ruby?

Tags: ruby, colors, gnome-terminal, ansi-escape

`printf "\033[1;32;40mGreen text on black background.\033[0m\n"`

That is the green, but how can i get light green or other variation of color?

http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html , are only those color available for gnome-terminal as escape code?

Also how can i get bigger font with ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using the "1" as the first parameter, as you are doing already, that's as "light" a green as you're going to get. this guy's webpage might be helpful: http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/May2004/article335.shtml

testing on urxvt:

[image: testing on urxvt not Gnome]

[added later] there is a DEC extension for double-sized characters: [Printing double-size characters with Ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470106/printing-double-size-characters-with-ncurses) but urxvt doesn't support it, I don't know about Gnome terminal.

Comment: How can i get more brighter/light green?How can i get bigger font too?

Comment: in an escape code? I don't believe it's possible using ANSI escapes. perhaps Gnome terminal has some extensions to ANSI but that's out of my expertise.

Comment: you only get two of each color, 31 through 37 (normal) and 1;31 through 1;37 (bold or bright)

Comment: hmm, I just noticed while testing that on urxvt, the bold colors actually use a larger font [nope, I was wrong, see new edit]

Answer (score 2):

With an offset of `90` you can create *bright/high contrast* colors.

See [here](http://jafrog.com/2013/11/23/colors-in-terminal.html) for a reference. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) mentions the *bright* color range, but doesn't really explain how to use them (if I haven't missed it).

If you combine it with the bold style you can create 4 variations of a color.

Example:

[image: 4 Shades of Blue]

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of the terminal support.  The ansi codes that you list are interpreted by the terminal emulator and those codes are the only available colours (it comes from the days before windows and when 16 colours caused a stir).

If you need more you could consider using a graphical interface to your ruby app such as tk.

Comment: How can i get bigger font too?

Comment: using tk as he suggests, you can use any font and font size, but then you are creating a graphical user interface; you are no longer using a text terminal.

Comment: Then when i change the font size from gnome-terminal>Edit>Preference, how is it changed? Why can't i change the font size programmaticaly?

Comment: perhaps Gnome terminal provides an API or some other "hooks" to change font and font size, or you could conceivably mimic the mouse movements and clicks necessary programmatically. for sure it can be done if you're willing to expend the time, research, and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an RGB escape code:

```
printf "\033[38;2;r;g;bmText\033[0m"
```

or, for background colour:

```
printf "\033[48;2;r;g;bmText\033[0m"
```

Just replace `r`, `g`, and `b` with the desired RGB value.